# Controls Layout Help in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a problem with layout

```
<ListBox Name="Tweets" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tweets}" Background="#1F0000FE">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:TweetTemplate Margin="10"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Here is my template:

```
<Grid Name="grid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="95*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Source="{Binding Path=FromImage}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="7" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=From}" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Grid.Row="1" Margin="7" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

My problem is when this `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}"` text is very long, it stretches the Grid. And then stretches Parent controls. I want that text don't stretch Listbox, and when it reaches the end of the ListBox width, switched to a new line. And when the window is resized, the size of ListBox should be increased. It means to use all of the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListBox creates ScrollViewer for displaying items, so you should manually disable it with  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility property:

```
    <ListBox Name="Tweets" 
             Grid.Row="1" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tweets}" 
             Background="#1F0000FE"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        ...
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Works better than my suggestion.  Go with it!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set a `MaxWidth` to the textblock, and set `TextWrapping="Wrap"`.  That should provide you with the desired results.  In your listbox you can also say `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` so that your Templated items stretch to the inside limits of the itemscontrol.

Comment: It doesnt helps me. I dont need fixed TextBlock, it should have width such as ListBox.

Comment: You can do some element property binding on the datatemplates grid like Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=booklist}" .  That would set the width to the listbox.  You might need to find a way to set it to the ItemsPresenters width though.